# Can we say "an illness /a condition/ a job... is fussy" when it needs to be precise and in great detail like a fussy eater?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

Some illness or conditions or jobs need their patients/ people to take care of themselves in great detail and if they do just a tiny mistake, they will suffer.

For example, **can we say?**

-"**Gut inflammation is very fussy. Eating just 1 milligram of chili can make the patient get diarrhea**"

-"**My accounting work is very fussy. Missing Just 1 cent, I will end up doing the whole report again**"

Comment: No, we can't. _Fussy_ describes a person or their behaviour, and calling someone a fussy eater implies that they choose to be particular about their food. It would be unkind to call someone whose diet is limited for medical reasons a fussy eater.

Comment: No to the diet; yes to the job (although it sounds like a stretch to these AmE ears).

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Kate Bunting: "Fussy describes a person or their behaviour, and calling someone a fussy eater implies that they choose to be particular about their food. It would be unkind to call someone whose diet is limited for medical reasons a fussy eater."

I'd add that the alternative words "finicky", "fastidious", "particular", "detailed", or "persnickety" would be appropriate.  In slang, I might use "putzy".